# Tables/Tabulares for SE

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

- Is it currently possible to add a [tabular](http://www.teamdf.com/files/display/178/crosstab_1.png) to a [question like this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47435/72471), e.g. to represent differences more clearly?

  - If not, then how hard is it to implement such a feature for SE sites and how can I contribute such a feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't; this feature was [requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables) on the main meta and [declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228464/145982):

> Just noticing that when we reviewed these proposals a while back, this one never got updated [even as the corresponding one on DBAs did](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/934/please-can-we-have-markdown-tables-on-dba-se/966#966).
>
> tl;dr: Implementing this in a way that wouldn't allow authors to break some / all page layouts, whether inadvertently or maliciously, is not feasible.
>
> I know. It sucks. But that's HTML tables for ya.

Comment: Damn that is really bad :(